# How do you deal with the native size of integers changing between platforms?

Tags: c++, c, portability

I'm afraid I already know the answer to this but I'd like to be sure...

I have a fairly large project with a header file that typedefs native types:

```
typedef unsigned long int    u32;
typedef signed long int      s32;
// etc...
```

The inevitable has happened and I am now trying to compile on a system where `long` is 64 bits instead of 32.  What is the best way to go about fixing it?

I could `typedef` the above with `int` (or `int32_t`/`uint32_t` from stdint.h) which would satisfy the 32bit size on the platforms I'm aware of but this still seems dubious.  There is also the problem with `printf` style functions where `%ld` was used (the compiler complains and would like to see `%d` instead).  These would all have to be changed, wouldn't they (perhaps with defines in inttypes.h)?

This seems straightforward but I would like to be sure before I start digging into it (fixing `printf` format strings seems daunting).

Comment: At what point does it actually matter? Why can't you just use `unsigned int`? That's portable, it's just not of a predictable size.

Comment: Your compiler should give warnings when you pass a non-`long` to a `%ld`, and with a flag you should be able make that warning into an error.  This gives you a chance to fix everything.

Comment: @Dietrich: that's fine for the majority of simple cases, where your format string is a literal right there in the call to `printf`. The compiler doesn't help though when the format string comes from elsewhere, such as a set of localised strings. This is one reason why it's a good idea to only use `%s` in such localisation strings, and convert numbers to strings before involving the language-specific code, or use something safer than varargs. If you've already done it the other way, though, it's a job to change it. So what you say is worth doing but doesn't fix everything.

Comment: @Steve Jessop: Fair, but you can usually define a macro to pass localized strings through as literals, and the remaining cases are relatively rare.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C has [`<stdint.h>`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stdint.h), which in C++0x is `<cstdint>`. For non-C++0x compilers, you have `<boost/cstdint.hpp>` if you don't mind reliance on Boost. The `<inttypes.h>` header also includes macros for `printf()` format specifiers, which can be [adapted for use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2747435/using-stdint-h-and-ansi-printf) with the `<cstdint>` types. If you're using C++, you should be using `<iostream>`, and consequently won't need to worry about typed format specifiers.

Comment: @Jon: you can always rip the header out of Boost (keep the license...), I suppose it's fairly independent...

Answer (score 1):

create a single translation (.cpp) which compiles with your library/executable. in it, use static asserts. if you need a specific size, this approach can confirm whether or not your declarations match the conditions you need them to match before you create a linkable/executable binary, should the environment ever change.

then turn up the compiler warnings and fix what must be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

The solution regarding a portable 32 bit integer (and the like):

- Define your own portable types in some hand-built configuration file or
- Use `stdint.h` which does this for you and is guaranteed to be there in any C compiler that is even close to C99 compatible.

As far as `printf` is concerned, `stdint.h` provides portable macros for `printf`. Or just use C++ I/O and then you don't have to worry about `printf` formats.

Comment: The `<stdint.h>` header does not contain the `printf` macros, that can be found in `<inttypes.h>`.